# Using Monte Carlo for computing circle area

Tags: r, montecarlo

I am trying to write a function circle_MC that takes the length of radius and the number of simulations (N) as an input and returns the area enclosed by a circle.

For doing that, I create a numeric vector and change it to "1", if the point is inside the circle, i.e. the ifelse statement holds.
My code so far:

```
circle_MC <- function(r, N)
{
  inside <- numeric(N),#only zeroes
  
  x_sim[i] <-  runif(N, min = -r, max = r),
  y_sim[i] <-  runif(N, min = -r, max = r),
  inside <- ifelse(x_sim^2[i] + y_sim^2[i] <= r, 1, 0),
  area <- (sum(inside)/length(inside)*4)
  
  return(area)
}
```

However, it gives me the error message "Error: unexpected '}' in "}".

I am pretty new to R and would love to understand where my mistake is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

THe issue is with the `,` at the end of each assignment.  Here, each assignment is a separate statement.  It is not clear where the `i` comes from as the arguments are only 'r' and 'N'

```
circle_MC <- function(r, N)
{
  inside <- numeric(N) #only zeroes removed , 
  
  x_sim <-  runif(N, min = -r, max = r) # removed ,
  y_sim <-  runif(N, min = -r, max = r)  # removed ,
  inside <- ifelse(x_sim^2 + y_sim^2 <= r, 1, 0) # removed ,
  area <- (sum(inside)/length(inside)*4)
  
  return(area)
}
```

Comment: Yes sorry, I also realized that it does not make sense using [i]. And thanks for pointing out the problem with the commas! I feel a little dumb now.

Comment: @programming_newbie I was doubtful regarding the `i`.  That is why I kept it. I will remove it

Comment: Yeah, I realized I needed to use it because of the for loop from another question. But for this specific task I do not need it.

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid `i` as it is not a loop (Updated thanks to @duckmayr):

```
#Function
circle_MC <- function(r, N)
{
  inside <- numeric(N)#only zeroes
  
  x_sim <-  runif(N, min = -r, max = r)
  y_sim <-  runif(N, min = -r, max = r)
  inside <- ifelse(x_sim^2 + y_sim^2 <= r^2, 1, 0)
  area <- ((sum(inside)/length(inside))*((2*r)^2))
  
  return(area)
}
```

Output:

```
#Code
circle_MC(2,100)

[1] 12.8
```

Comment: Just FYI, the math here is wrong also (though this isn't what the OP was asking about). The `ifelse()` condition should use `r^2` rather than `r`; i.e., change `ifelse(x_sim^2 + y_sim^2 <= r, 1, 0)` to `ifelse(x_sim^2 + y_sim^2 <= r^2, 1, 0)`, and the last part should not use `4` but rather `(2*r)^2`; i.e., change `(sum(inside)/length(inside)*4)` to `((sum(inside)/length(inside))*((2*r)^2))`. For example, you can tell that in your "Output" section, 1.6 is not the area of that circle, and it doesn't get closer by upping the N. Making these changes gives you the approximate correct answer

Comment: @duckmayr Can I update the answer with your useful insights?

Comment: @duckmayr Thanks for the help. I have updated the function with your insights (credits to you)!